# which is correct either "my playing" or "playing my"

Tags: possessives

Do following two words can be used interchangeably for making a sentence?
**which is correct either "my playing" or "playing my".**

Comment: We need context.  They are both correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the context, so it's hard to say.

If you were to say "I am playing my guitar" then thats perfectly correct, where *playing* is a verb and *my* is referring to the guitar.

The phrase *my playing* is probably slightly less common, less likely to be heard, and it took me a while to even think of a sentence in which to use it. That being said, it is still correct when used as a gerund. For example, "does my playing here annoy you?" Here, the *playing here* is a verb-as-a-noun, and the *my* refers to the act of playing. I would say this sentence is rather formal, and you would be more likely to here, "does it annoy you if I play here?" / "Is it annoying if I play here" etc.

Comment: Please avoid premature answers. A question that is unclear - needs context or detail - can't be answered properly until the OP makes the necessary changes.